# Is there any method to solve this probability and find an closed form expression?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-distribution, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose I have Shannon's rate equation $$R = \sum_{i=1}^{N}\log\left(1+\frac{P\gamma_i}{\sigma^2}\right).$$ Here $N$ is the number of OFDMA subcarriers, and $\gamma_i$ are channel coefficients that are exponentially distributed random variables. $P$ and $\sigma^2$ are transmitted power and noise variance, respectively, which are constant terms.

Finally, we have to find the outage probability  $Pr(R<t)$.

Here $t$ is some predefined threshold. Is there any way to solve this outage probability?